# What does a taxi...cost?

Tags: nouns

Does the following make sense?

What does a **taxi** to the hotel cost?

Should "ride" be placed after "taxi"?

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

You could put "ride" after "taxi," but it's not necessary.  Any reasonable listener would understand that you are not actually buying a taxi car, just paying for a ride on one. So your sentence is grammatically correct and easily understood.

However, it is more idiomatic to use the question words "how much...?" rather than "what...?" when you are asking about a numeric quantity, including an amount of money:

> How much does a taxi to the hotel cost?

And with the "how much..." in this context, it's again obvious to any reasonable listener that you're asking about a cost, so you can even leave that part out, but you'd also change the verb to **is**:

> How much is a taxi to the hotel?

This last one is the most idiomatic and is probably what you'd hear from a native speaker.

Comment: Are you saying "what" is unidiomatic in the sense of "how much"? What about "What do you earn before/after tax"?

Comment: Hm.  I've been thinking about this.  I do think that "what" is less idiomatic than "how much" when asking about prices in particular, but not strongly so. It's certainly true that if you leave off the "cost", then "What is a taxi to the hotel?" is not idiomatic at all.

Comment: How much is the taxi, what does x cost, for a product, and what do you earn before taxes. But there are situations when one might say cost for a taxi. It depends....if you are an accountant or other situations.